# Bootstrap dropdown nav is not dropping down

Tags: html, menu

I'm using Bootstrap classes to create a dropdown list of navigation links in the nav bar. But for some reason the drop down is not appearing when I click on the menu icon. Can someone kindly help me see what I'm not seeing?

```html
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"></li><a class="nav-link" href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"></li><a class="nav-link" href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"></li><a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"></li><a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                            <button class="btn my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                          </form>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar issue to yours, I solved it by using bootstrap.bundle.js instead of bootstrap.js.  I had an error pop up in the console telling me that there was no popper.js, which is a library that boostrap uses.  It is bundled with bootstrap when using bootstrap.bundle.js.